# sql server 2005 :how to put not null constraint on a column depending upon value in other column?

Tags: null, conditional-statements

in a table two of columns are billable(bit),billabledate(datetime).i want billable date to be not null if billable is not null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a check constraint:

CHECK (billable is not null and billabledate is not null) OR (billable is null)

Answer (score 2):

You need a Check Constraint

ALTER TABLE dbo.Table WITH NOCHECK
      ADD  CONSTRAINT CK_Table_BusinessRule
      CHECK (Billable IS NOT NULL AND BillableDate IS NOT NULL)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179491(SQL.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'd try adding a trigger to the table, on after insert and after update, to enforce that constraint.
Check the billable value, and block insert/update in case it is not null and the billabledate is null.